# ggplot2: inaccurate fills in layered plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following. Why do I not get accurate fills and labeling? Why do I only get a single color fill? Note that the non loop version works perfectly

```
data(iris)
xx <- list(iris, iris)
xx[[1]]$Sepal.Length <- rnorm(150)
xx[[2]]$Sepal.Length <- rnorm(150,mean = 10)

cols <- c("low" = "#e41a1c", "high"= "#377eb8")
p2 <- p <- ggplot() 
for (i in 1:2) {
  p <- p + geom_histogram(data=xx[[i]], aes(x= Sepal.Length, stat(density), fill= factor(names(cols)[i])))
  p2 <- p2 + geom_histogram(data=xx[[i]], aes(x= Sepal.Length, stat(density), fill= factor(cols[i])))
}
p + scale_fill_manual(values= cols)
p2 + scale_fill_manual(values= cols)

iris <- xx[[1]]
iris2 <- xx[[2]]
p3 <- ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data= iris, aes(x= Sepal.Length, stat(density), fill= factor("low"))) +
  geom_histogram(data= iris2, aes(x= Sepal.Length, stat(density), fill= factor("high"))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= cols)
p3
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: That's expected behavior.

`aes(x= Sepal.Length, stat(density), fill= factor(cols[i]))`

will hold the expression `factor(cols[i])`, and evaluate it until the expression is needed. In your case, it's the two lines after for loop, where  `i == 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hypothesis was that the call stack evaluates lazily. That is, mapping the fill to `names(cols)[i]` without evaluating that expression. Hence, the mapping is identical in `scale_fill_manual`.

This ends up being correct. As @maurits evers notes above, `ggplot2` isn't designed to accommodate this use case. The below works

```
# @description Process a set of input data.frame's to extract only the 
# column of interest and assign a group name
dtlist_inputs <- function(dt_list, varname, groups, input= TRUE) {
  dt_list <- do.call('rbind', (mapply(function(l, groupname, varname) {
    return(data.frame(
      group= groupname
      , var= get(varname, as.environment(l))
    ))
    }, l= dt_list, groupname= groups, varname= varname, SIMPLIFY= FALSE))) 
  return(dt_list)
}

# @description Histogram for multiple groups, where each group is input as a separate data.frame.
# @param dt_list a \code{list} of \code{data.frame}s
# @param cols a named vector of colour hexes.
# @varname A \code{character} scalar denoting the variable in each element of \code{dt_list} you wish to plot.
# @binwidth To be passed to `\code{\link[ggplot2]{geom_histogram}}.
# @x_lab To be passed to `\code{\link[ggplot2]{labs}}.
# @grouptitle To be passed to `\code{\link[ggplot2]{guides}} for legend label.
# @x_breaks To be passed to `\code{\link[ggplot2]{scale_x_continuous}} for axis breaks.
GGgroup_histogram <- function(dt_list, cols, varname, binwidth= 0.02,
        grouptitle= "Error Group", 
        x_lab= "Variable", x_breaks= seq(0,1,.1)) {
  if (length(dt_list) != length(cols)) stop("length of dt_list and cols must match.")

  dt_list <- dtlist_inputs(dt_list, varname, groups= names(cols))
  sub_title <- paste("Variable:", varname)

  p <- ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(data= dt_list, aes(x=var, stat(density), fill= factor(group)),
                   binwidth= binwidth, alpha= 0.5)
  p <- p + labs(y= "Density", x= x_lab,
             title= "Distributional differences in relative abs error between groups",
             subtitle= sub_title) +
    scale_fill_manual(values= cols) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks= x_breaks) +
    guides(fill= guide_legend(title= grouptitle)) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
          axis.title= element_text(face= "bold", size= 11),
          axis.text= element_text(size= 10),
          plot.title= element_text(face= "bold.italic", size= 13),
          plot.subtitle= element_text(face= "bold.italic", size= 12))
  return(p)
}
```

**Edit** We can also compare the idea of using `dplyr::bind_rows` (suggested above), vs my natural tendency to prefer `data.table::rbindlist`:

```
set.seed(6231)
d <- data.frame(x1= rnorm(1000), x2= rnorm(1000), x3= rnorm(100))
d <- replicate(n= 10, expr= d, simplify = FALSE)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
     base= do.call('rbind', d),
     dplyr= dplyr::bind_rows(d),
     data.table= data.table::rbindlist(d)
)

Unit: microseconds
       expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq        max neval cld
       base 697.373 783.108 2484.0814 842.7745 923.9245 121350.787   100   a
      dplyr 161.385 186.140  279.2899 211.4355 229.4350   3488.347   100   a
 data.table 108.853 137.612  247.6596 159.0105 181.3150   5874.138   100   a

## with replicate(... n= 1000)
Unit: milliseconds
   expr        min         lq      mean     median        uq       max neval cld
      base 211.718863 480.355404 707.60993 722.989094 948.77399 1020.6656   100   b
     dplyr  16.597688  18.184643  72.09627  21.374848  25.19133  293.0039   100  a 
data.table   3.122027   3.480451  49.24004   6.545908   9.54836  270.4440   100  a
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not the `ggplot` way.

Instead, consider doing the following

```
data(iris)
xx <- list(iris, iris)
xx[[1]]$Sepal.Length <- rnorm(150)
xx[[2]]$Sepal.Length <- rnorm(150,mean = 10)

cols <- c("low" = "#e41a1c", "high"= "#377eb8")
names(xx) <- names(cols)

library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(xx, .id = "Key") %>%
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, fill = Key)) +
    geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Explanation: We row-bind `data.frame`s in the `list`, storing the name of the `list` element in `Key`. We then have a single `data.frame` and use the `fill` aesthetic to map different `Key`s to different fills.